# How do I get the transaction timestamp from a block?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

How can I use fabric-sdk-go to get the transaction timestamp from the block?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: I tried to parse the block, but I don't know how to use fabric-sdk-go to get the transaction data in the block.

Comment: I know you are new to posting, but it would be helpful if you could modify your question to include a snippet of any code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. TimeStamp can be obtained by parsing *common.BlockData, which is contained in *common.ChannelHeader.